# Issue with using Dockerfile to build image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have trouble with using **dockerfile** to build image.

**dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:4.4

MAINTAINER paas  

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.11.6-1~jessie

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62 \

&& echo "deb nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \

&& apt-get update \

&& apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \

ca-certificates \

nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} \

nginx-module-xslt \

nginx-module-geoip \

nginx-module-image-filter \

nginx-module-perl \

nginx-module-njs \

gettext-base \

curl \

&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled


# SSL Certificate Installation

ADD star_dar_kz.key /etc/ssl/

# ADD star_dar_kz.pem /etc/ssl/
# ADD dhparam.pem /etc/ssl/

# ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
# ADD merchants.dar.kz.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli

RUN npm install --global bower

RUN npm install

RUN bower --allow-root install

RUN gulp build --env prod

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And after `docker build`, the GPG line appears as red and image creation fails. Why?

> ```
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
> Step 1/16 : FROM node:4.4
>  ---> 93b396996a16
> Step 2/16 : MAINTAINER Nurbek Sadykov
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> e9a0bc967863
> Step 3/16 : ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.11.6-1~jessie
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 3e87467bd365
> Step 4/16 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62     && echo "deb h:/nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y                         ca-certificates                         nginx=${NGINX_VERSION}                         nginx-module-xslt                         nginx-module-geoip                         nginx-module-image-filter                         nginx-module-perl                         nginx-module-njs                         gettext-base                                                 curl     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
>  ---> Running in 93f88784bc24
> Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.acoVZ86x3m --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62
> **gpg: requesting key 7BD9BF62 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu**
> **gpg: key 7BD9BF62: public key "nginx signing key " imported**
> **gpg: Total number processed: 1**
> **gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)** - ** THIS IS INDICATED IN RED COLOR**
> Get:1 url InRelease [63.1 kB]
> Get:2 url InRelease [2865 B]
> Ign url jessie InRelease
> Get:3 url jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
> Get:4 url amd64 Packages [37.3 kB]
> Get:5 url jessie Release.gpg [2373 B]
> Get:6 urljessie Release [148 kB]
> Get:7 url amd64 Packages [613 kB]
> Get:8 url amd64 Packages [23.2 kB]
> Get:9 url jessie/main amd64 Packages [9063 kB]
> Fetched 10.1 MB in 5s (1835 kB/s)
> Reading package lists...
> Reading package lists...
> Building dependency tree...
> Reading state information...
> **Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming**.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  nginx-module-geoip : Depends: nginx (= 1.13.7-1~jessie)
>  nginx-module-image-filter : Depends: nginx (= 1.13.7-1~jessie)
>  nginx-module-njs : Depends: nginx (= 1.13.7-1~jessie)
>  nginx-module-perl : Depends: nginx (= 1.13.7-1~jessie)
>  nginx-module-xslt : Depends: nginx (= 1.13.7-1~jessie)
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> The command '/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62     && echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y                         ca-certificates                         nginx=${NGINX_VERSION}                         nginx-module-xslt                         nginx-module-geoip                         nginx-module-image-filter                         nginx-module-perl                         nginx-module-njs                         gettext-base                                                 curl     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
> ```

Comment: Hi @Joom187, please clean up your question by using code blocks for your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

There were three issues in your Dockerfile:

1. Incorrect url to nginx packages
2. Nginx modules should be the same version as nginx
3. There is no version `1.11.6-1~jessie` for module `nginx-module-njs`, so we need to add one more ENV variable.

The final Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:4.4

MAINTAINER paas  

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.11.6-1~jessie
ENV NGINX_MODULE_NJS 1.11.6.0.1.4-2~jessie

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62 \
&& echo 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
ca-certificates \
nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} \
nginx-module-xslt=${NGINX_VERSION} \
nginx-module-geoip=${NGINX_VERSION} \
nginx-module-image-filter=${NGINX_VERSION} \
nginx-module-perl=${NGINX_VERSION} \
nginx-module-njs=${NGINX_MODULE_NJS} \
gettext-base \
curl \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

# SSL Certificate Installation 
ADD star_dar_kz.key /etc/ssl/

# ADD star_dar_kz.pem /etc/ssl/
# ADD dhparam.pem /etc/ssl/

# ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
# ADD merchants.dar.kz.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli

RUN npm install --global bower

RUN npm install

RUN bower --allow-root install

RUN gulp build --env prod

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Kolyan spasibo tebe bolwoe!